# SSRS Report Chart and LookupSet

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a tablix that contains a LookUpSet for a Site

```
=Join(Lookupset(Fields!VCC_MSID.Value,
     Fields!VCC_MS.Value,
     Fields!Site.Value, 
     "Agents"))
```

but the dataset used for this tablix does not contain the site value (which is the SQL Query).  I need to create a chart based on site, but I don't have a way of using the dataset with the Site included in it.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to re-develop your datasets to include all the information you need.

Comment: So there's no way to add a chart and use in some way the Join(Lookupset...) I figured it is not possible because when I checked the configuration for the charts x and y axis it does not provide an expression where I can use the join(lookupset...) code. thanks.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are actually asking. What is your source data (an exanple)? What do you want your output to be? And what have you tried so far? Without this we can't really help further...

Comment: The source data that I have does not include "site" field it is joined through another data set since our system does not allow link server in SQL (see code above) . So then I use the code above and place it as an expression in the Category Groups in Charts. make sense?